# gzip and pipe to output (performance consideration)

Tags: linux, unix, encryption, gzip, solaris

q1) Can i check if I do a 
gzip -c file | encrypt (some parameters)

a) does gzip print out the output line by line and pipe it to the encrypt function or

b) gzip will be perform 1st, then the output will be pipe all at once to the encrypt function ?

====================================================

q2) Will performing gzip | encrypt have any better performance considerations then gzip, then encrypt

Regards,
Noob

Comment: I don't think the concept of `lines` applies to the compressed stream. For the second part, you can always run comparisons on your data: `time <command>`.  Performing through the pipe should be the best choice, as the latter requires creation of an intermediate file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gzip is a streaming compressor/decompressor. So (for large enough inputs) the compressor/decompressor starts writing output before it has seen the whole input.

That's one of the reasons gzip compression is used for HTTP compression. The sender can compress while it's still generating content; the recipient can work on decompressing the first part of the content, while still receiving the rest.

Gzip does not work "line-by-line", because it doesn't know what a line is. But it does work "chunk-by-chunk", where the compressor defines the size of the chunk.

"Performance" is too vague a word, and too complex an area to give a yes or no answer.

With `gzip -c file | encrypt`, for a large enough file, will see `encrypt` and `gzip` working concurrently. That is, `encrypt` will be encrypting the first compressed block *before* `gzip` compresses the last chunk of file.

Comment: where can i read more about gzip being a stream based compressor/decompressor, pardon my ignorance, i didn't know about this until posting the question here.

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of thing you want to find out. It's not really something that gets written down, since streaming is the "normal" way for UNIX tools to work when they can.

Comment: can you elaborate further on what is a stream -> do you mean that data get "pour" into gzip and "flow" out of gzip; but who and what decides how much of data get in and out ?

Comment: @Noob all "streaming" means is that the program alternates between reading and writing. So you start getting output before it's finished consuming input. Most UNIX utilities do this. For example `grep` writes a matching line immediately after reading it. Those that don't, do it because they can't. For example `sort` reading from stdin has no way to know that the last line won't be `aardvark`, so it can't start writing until the input is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a pipe buffer is implementation dependent.  Under SunOS, it's 4kB.  That is: `gunzip < file.gz | encrypt` will move in 4k chunks.  Again, it depends on the OS.  CygWIN might behave completely differently.

I should add that this is in `man 7 pipe`.  Search for **PIPE_BUF**.

Comment: yes the pipe buffer is 4kB, but how much will the gzip or gunzip "pours" into the pipe per time ?  if the pipe buffer is not full (not 4kB yet), will the pipe redirect its buffer to another side of the pipe?

Comment: The gunzip process will block until the reader empties out its side of the pipe.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: i mean in gzip -c file | encrypt, you mention the size of the pipe is 4k, but how much will gzip -c file output per time ?

Comment: I don't know how gzip is implemented, but I'm guessing it has to do with the size of the dictionary it is using.  For the purposes of the programmer, you would probably never know (or care).  For example, it's common to do something like: `gzcat <file.tar.gz | tar tf -`
In this case, neither `gzcat` nor `tar` care about the size of the pipe.  They will simply read/write until they block and then resume when I/O is available.  Is this helping?